# what is the cause of ORA-02185: error?

Tags: oracle

I am facing this strange error. I am coping a query from a  script to pl/sql on command window:

```
COMMIT
/
DELETE FROM PARAMETERS where LOV_TYPE_ID = 221
/
```

the result in dialog is:

```
COMMIT
/?
DELETE FROM PARAMETERS  where LOV_TYPE_ID = 221

ORA-02185: a token other than WORK follows COMMIT
```

There is a strange `?`. I added the word `WORK` next to the commit, the error persist. But when I re-write the query `commit / delete..`, it works, but the problem is, the script have many `commit` and `delete`.

Comment: delete... whereid=221; then commit; (with semi-colons)

Comment: @Randy I cannot add ; because the scripts are used in java application and the application library does not allow ';' the '/' should used . If you want I can send attach of script

Comment: Does your DELETE statement *really* contain the literal string 'where LOV_TYPE_ID = 221<br/>' ? (note the <br/> tag)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt no no my mistake i add br/ by mistake and i remove it

Comment: Strange! reading it in 2022 and still looks familiar. my case the script always worked even when i was getting the same error on the server console.

Comment: @Vaibs its something realte to utf8 of the notpadd or script editor you are using.

Answer (score 0):

COMMIT should be followed by a semicolon ';'
like this 'COMMIT;'